# Shadow root cannot be created on a host which already hosts a shadow tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shadow

I'm rendering a react app(Widget) inside Shadow DOM. So I looked at the div id where the widget is getting loaded currently.

See screenshow below. [image]

With this information, I want to create Shadow host like this.

```
const host = document.querySelector('#widget-_hw');
const shadow = host.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
const renderIn = document.createElement('div');
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
Failed to execute 'attachShadow' on 'Element': Shadow root cannot be created on a host which already hosts a shadow tree
```

Comment: So you are reading the element before it exists. You can not eat your pizza before it is made.

Comment: Your point was correct. I changed the place where I called querySelector so host exist now. 

But now I'm getting another set of error.

Comment: could you please post the answer if you got it?